# Magento 2.1 with new domain and I can't login into admin anymore

Tags: magento-2.1, domain

We just go our real domain pointed to our VPS with Magento 2.1 on it.

**Before:** dev.domain.com

**Now:** www.domain.com

The shop is working more or less ok with a few hiccups.

We have already changed the **`base_url`** and the **`secure_base_url`**.

I can't login into the admin area anymore without any error message.

Nothing on the login page - I'm just being returned to the login.

Nothing in system, exception or debug.log.

I already found this one here:

[SOLVED - Magento 2 - Unable to login to admin (no error message) stuck at login screen](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160775/solved-magento-2-unable-to-login-to-admin-no-error-message-stuck-at-login)

but I don't have "cookie" at all in `core_config_data`.

Until yesterday, I never had any problems to login to the admin area with the subdomain dev.domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try incognito mode, I have something similar happen on my dev sites and I know its with cookies but never quite pinpointed it.

If that works maybe clear cookies for the old domain.

Also, I think this is a reason to use www. in your Magento domains because otherwise the cookies get shared in some way that doesn't work with these kinds of set ups.