# Magento 2.4.3 p1 admin login not working

Tags: magento2.4.3

After the new Magento 2.4.3p1 setup, I am not able to login

http://prntscr.com/1y62cy6

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new admin user via the command line or reset the password by forgetting the password feature (if emails are working).

You can use the below comment to create a new admin.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --admin-email=hi@test.com --admin-firstname=test --admin-lastname=test
```

If still not working then you need to check the cookie and session value that is set in the system configurable. Please review the below doc, which will help you to set the correct setting.
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/customer-online-options.html

[SOLVED - Magento 2 - Unable to login to admin (no error message) stuck at login screen](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160775/solved-magento-2-unable-to-login-to-admin-no-error-message-stuck-at-login)
(Last comment)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I try it but not working

Comment: Try in firefox.

Comment: There are 4 solutions to this problem. I have listed these solutions here https://www.thecoachsmb.com/solved-admin-login-error/ Do mention which one worked for you.